# Set breakpoint on Entity Framework database call

Tags: entity-framework, debugging, entity-framework-5

Is it possible to set a breakpoint on every database call that's being made by the Entity Framework? This would be a very simple way to debug where unexpected database calls are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I included the MiniProfiler (StackExchange.Profiling) source code projects, and set a breakpoint in the `ProfiledDbCommand` constructor with the condition `command.CommandText != ""`.

Maybe there is even a better spot to set a breakpoint, but this works for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible since there are tools like [Entity Framework Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf) and [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) that do this. But I don't think it is very trivial to implement this on your own for quick debugging purposes.

You don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I suggest giving those two tools a try. Entity Framework Profiler even [shows you where in your code each query originated](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/imgs/ScreenShots-EFProf-StatementStacktraces.png) and you can even click on the points of origin to jump to that location in Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried the MiniProfiler, a very useful library. But for some situations I think normal debugging with a proper call stack and debugging info is a lote more useful. I will take a look at EF Profiler!

Answer (score 1):

You could try Intellitrace - When debugging with VS 2012 open the Intellitrace window (Debug -> Windows -> Intellitrace Events). There you should see all the queries sent to the database. Select the query and click "Call Stack".